# hidden input got chunked after space

Tags: django, django-forms

Here's my use case:

I've a hidden input like this:

```
{% block content %}
<form method= "post" action ="/new_stuff/">
<input type = "hidden"  name = "myinput" id="myinput" value ={{myinputvalue}}></input>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

in this html page, the `myinputvalue` value was correct: `AB CD`, however, when I submit this form, this `myinputvalue` value got chunked after space, it became `AB`, I'm confused why this happens, thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it in quotes.

```
value="{{myinputvalue}}"
```

Comment: You rock! :) I really wish I could have spotted this error myself. But how come I could get the first part of it even without quotes?